# Animate rotation and location of view at same time

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

What is the best way to rotate a view and move its location at the same time?

I want this view to rotate 1 full revolution while sliding to the left, then rotate the other direction while sliding back to its original position. I got the first part of this working (rotate while sliding to left), but when I try to rotate while sliding back to the right, the view jumps back to its original spot without animating.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// step 1 (this works)
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        self.number.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(180));
        self.number.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-160, 0);
        self.number.center = CGPointMake(self.number.center.x - 160, self.number.center.y);
    } completion:nil];

// step 2 (this doesn't work)
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        self.number.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(180));
        self.number.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(160, 0);
        self.number.center = CGPointMake(self.number.center.x + 160, self.number.center.y);
    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Is number made in a storyboard, and do you have auto layout turned on?

Comment: Also, do you want one full revolution? Your code shoes that you're doing a 180.

Comment: Number's made in a NIB, and yes auto-layout is turned on (though there's no constraints applied to it). And yes I want one full revolution - the code shows a 180, but in practice it does a full 360 for some reason.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 5? You can't have a view with no constraints. The system will add them for you at run time, if you don't put them in. If you log DegreesToRadians(180) what does it give you? I get quite different results than you in xCode 4.6. Step 1 flips the view upside down immediately, then rotates 180 degrees over the duration time, and doesn't translate at all (I do have constraints set, and I'm using M_PI in place of your DegreesToRadians(180)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the following code. My view had a constraint to the left side of the superview, to which I added the IBOutlet, leftCon. It's initial value was 160, so the translation moves it all the way to the left edge of the screen.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#define animationTime 1.0

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat leftConstant;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.leftConstant = self.leftCon.constant;
}


- (IBAction)rotate:(UIButton *)sender {
     if (self.leftCon.constant == self.leftConstant) {
        [self.view removeConstraint:self.leftCon];
        CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        rotationAnimation.toValue = @(-M_PI * 2.0);
        rotationAnimation.duration = animationTime;

        CABasicAnimation *translationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        translationAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.number.center];
        translationAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.number.frame.size.width/2.0, self.number.center.y)];
        translationAnimation.duration = animationTime;
        [self.number.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
        [self.number.layer addAnimation:translationAnimation forKey:@"translationAnimation"];
        self.leftCon.constant = 0;
        [self.view addConstraint:self.leftCon];
     }else{
         [self.view removeConstraint:self.leftCon];
         CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
         rotationAnimation.toValue = @(M_PI * 2.0);
         rotationAnimation.duration = animationTime;

         CABasicAnimation *translationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
         translationAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.number.center];
         translationAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.leftConstant+ self.number.frame.size.width/2.0, self.number.center.y)];
         translationAnimation.duration = animationTime;
         [self.number.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
         [self.number.layer addAnimation:translationAnimation forKey:@"translationAnimation"];
         self.leftCon.constant = self.leftConstant;
         [self.view addConstraint:self.leftCon];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to place your second animation as the completion block in the first animation.

Comment: I can't - they're two separate actions. The first is performed when a UITableViewCell is selected, the second when it's deselected.

Comment: Ah ok - I thought it should happen directly one after another. Is that actually the code you use? I am surpsrised that it rotates at all, as you just replace the transform matrix. Also, adding translation *and* moving the center seems buggy.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too, but without changing the center at the same time the view jumps around before it animates.

Comment: Maybe just a wrong anchor point for your rotation? Typically you compose translation, rotation, and another rotation into a single matrix.